# What is the release schedule for tensorflow-serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I didn't want to make an issue for this on github because it didn't seem appropriate as this isn't a bug-

I can't find any documentation for the release schedule of tensorflow-serving. Tensorflow 1.14.0 is out, but the last serving release was 1.14.0rc0. I'm sure TF-Serving 1.14.0 will follow shortly, but it would help me greatly to know when. I see some variance between previous tensorflow release dates and corresponding tensorflow-serving releases. Is there a release schedule somewhere? Or else a mailing list? There doesn't seem to be a TF SIG group for serving.

Comment: I had the same question, I was told to ask in: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/tfx, so I just did that now.

Comment: TensorFlow Serving 1.14.0 finally tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @WilliamD.Irons - looks like there is a [google group for TensorFlow Extended](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/tfx), which includes serving. As for the TFServing release schedule-

> ...the goal is to closely follow TF's release schedule.

from https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msg/tfx/A_qfIooNGsk/iayJ5D6cCgAJ

Answer (score 0):

1.14.0: it was just released last night. Please find the below link for Release Notes.

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/releases/tag/1.14.0